# Adding a button to the bottom of a gridview in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-gridview

Ive been trying unsuccessfully for a few days now to get a button to sit at the bottom of a gridview, I have still not been able to get the to work and havent been able to find a working solution anywhere, has anyone done this before? below is my code and an example of what Im trying to achieve, any help would go an extremely long way, thank you so much if you can give me an answer that actually works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_user_avatar"
        android:layout_width="48px"
        android:layout_height="48px"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_realname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:gravity="left" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tweets_stat"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/button_color_light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/button_color_dark"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Tweets"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/followers_stat"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/button_color_light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/button_color_dark"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Followers"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/following_stat"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/button_color_light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/button_color_dark"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Following"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/profile_button"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:text="Load more photos" />
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I would actually scratch all your view groups and just use one RelativeLayout. This would not only make everything easier to read, but it'll speed up your View drawing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/profile_button"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:text="Load more photos" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/profile_button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree w/ @Frank Sposaro  but try using: `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/feature_add_confirm_buttons"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/feature_add_cancel_btn"
            android:text="@string/button_cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>


<GridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/feature_add_confirm_buttons"
    android:id="@+id/feature_grid_types"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="30dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="30dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

</GridView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I wound up fixing it by not using a gridview at all, I instead used a listview and simply added 3 images per cell, I used this tactic to also make a header with different content as well, very useful trick!